# Django ModeViewSet: SerializerMethodField not getting called

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I try to use SerializerMethodField to customize url of FileField in my API (url should return absolute url with site domain). Currently, it return "http://[IP]/media/[my-file-name] which is not a valid url.

I have followed DRF documentation of ModelViewSet and SerializerMethodField.
But audio_url and pictogramme_url are not displayed when calling my API via Postman (GET http://[my-site-domain]/api/risk/2/).

It seems that get_audio_url and get_pictogramme_url methods are not called.
More surprisingly, if I change fields attribute in RiskSerializer to control fields rendered (for example fields = ['id', 'label', 'created_at', 'created_by']), it doesn't seems to have any impact.

I have found many post on SO but can't find any answer to solve my problem.

## api/views.py

```
class RiskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Risk.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RiskSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({'request': self.request})
        return context
```

## api/serializers.py

```
class RiskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ A class to create a Risk serializer instance. """
    
    audio_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    pictogramme_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta():
        model = Risk
        fields = ['id', 'label', 'activated', 'audio_url', 'pictogramme_url', 'created_at', 'created_by']
        # fields = '__all__'

    def get_audio_url(self, risk):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        audio_url = risk.audio.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(audio_url)

    def get_pictogramme_url(self, risk):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        pictogramme_url = risk.pictogramme.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(pictogramme_url)
```

## api/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("risk", RiskViewSet, basename='risk')
app_name="api"
urlpatterns = [
    # API
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: I think you are not using the right serializer in the viewset. Also you do not need to override the `get_serializer_context` because modelviewset automatically sends the request via context.

Comment: serializer_class = RiskSerializer should be right to use the right serializer?

Comment: I've tried on my RegisterViewSet that use User as a model and defined days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField() like in DRF documentation exampale and it works... I do not understand what is wrong in my RiskSerializer

Comment: you were right, I had redefined another RiskSerializer below in my serializers.py file